# Unable to prevent 'list index out of range' error in fibonacci 'for' loop iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm still something of a beginner with Python and I was trying to optimise a function to generate the Fibonacci sequence to a specified number of values. This is the code I have written:

```
def attempt2(length):
    listy=[]
    for i in range(0,length+1):
        if i == 0:
            listy.append(1)
        elif i == 1:
            listy.append(1)
        else:
            listy.append(listy[i]+listy[i-1])
    return listy
```

Whilst keeping this structure I have found no way to overcome the 'list index out of range' error. I think because the listy[i-1] would be out of range when i = 0, but if the function progresses through the loop linearly then the else statement should only take effect when i = 2. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: When i = 2: ```listy.append(listy[2]+listy[1])``` But ```listy[2]``` is not defined. maybe it should be ```listy.append(listy[i-2]+listy[i-1])```

Comment: Ahh I see, you're right, it was tracking one ahead, the update you suggested makes it work properly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to find out the source of your issue, we need to take a step back to see what your loop is doing.

Initially, your for-loop is counting from 0 to whatever the length is, let's see what the values for i will look like:

0
1
2
...

so starting from 2, since the behavior of 0,1 is defined:

```
listy.append(listy[2]+listy[1])
```

Remember that listy has 2 items now, which are **zero indexed**, in other words the items are 1 and 0, hence the item listy[2] doesn't exist.

Thus, your code should be

```
listy.append(listy[i-2]+listy[i-1])
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it for me, I'm still learning so thanks for explaining it in detail, all the best!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good solution overall but the tiny mistake is that you should change line 9 to:

```
            listy.append(listy[i - 1] + listy[i - 2])
```

---

Also you'll have a `length + 1` size list not `length`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong list indices

```
def attempt2(length):
    listy=[]
    for i in range(0,length):
        if i == 0:
            listy.append(1)
        elif i == 1:
            listy.append(1)
        else:
            listy.append(listy[i -1]+listy[i - 2])
    return listy

print(attempt2(12))

#[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
```

Answer (score 0):

Listy[-1] returns the last element of your list. 
List position is initialising at 0 not 1. 
When i = 2, in your else statement 
listy.append(listy[i]+listy[i-1]) is equivalent to listy.append(listy[2]+listy[1])
Yet, your list after the second loop is equal to [1,1]. 
The max pos is 1 and 2 is out of range.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def loop_fib(n):
    # first two numbers are 1
    fib_1=1
    fib_2=1
    res=[1,1]
    # n is inclusive
    for i in range(3,n+1):
        # new fib_2=fib_1+fib_2
        # new fib_1=old fib_2
        fib_1,fib_2=fib_2,fib_1+fib_2
        res.append(fib_2)
    return res


loop_fib(10)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```